# How does modulus operation works with float data type?

Tags: c#, .net, floating-point, modulo

I m trying to find out a simple modulus operation on float data type.

```
float a=3.14f;
float b=10f;
result=a%b;
```

I m getting result= 3.14

Another example using decimal data types:

```
decimal p=10;
decimal q=40;
result=p%q;
```

getting answer=20.

I am not understanding how does modulus works?

Comment: Do you understand how `%` works with integers?

Comment: I know I'm late to the party, but 10%40 should be 0. % get's the remainder of the division.

Comment: @jtsmith1287 if the remainder is 0, then what is the quotient, and where does the left over 10 go?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. 10m % 40m returns a decimal 10, as expected, not 20 as claimed.

Answer (score 21):

From the C# language spec on floating point remainder.  In the case of `x % y` if `x` and `y` are positive finite values.

> `z` is the result of `x % y` and is computed as `x – n * y`, where `n`
>   is the largest possible integer that is less than or equal to `x / y`.

The C# language spec  also clearly outlines the table of what to do with the cases of all possible combinations of nonzero finite values, zeros, infinities, and NaN’s which can occur with floating point values of x % y.

> ```
>                           y value
>
>                 | +y  –y  +0  –0  +∞  –∞  NaN
>            -----+----------------------------  
>   x         +x  | +z  +z  NaN NaN x   x   NaN
>             –x  | –z  –z  NaN NaN –x  –x  NaN
>   v         +0  | +0  +0  NaN NaN +0  +0  NaN
>   a         –0  | –0  –0  NaN NaN –0  –0  NaN
>   l         +∞  | NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
>   u         –∞  | NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
>   e         NaN | NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
> ```

Comment: I always think of it as the result of subtracting y from x repeatedly unless/until x is less than y. (Which is obviously much less efficient, but easier for me to grasp in my head.)

Answer (score 7):

This article on msdn has sufficient example but I can explain it real quick;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx

If you do `int result = x % y;` what you'll find is that you are returned the remainder of `x % y` and the values are treated more like whole numbers. For example, the third line in the link is `Console.WriteLine(5.0 % 2.2);` which prints `.6`. This is because it finds that 2.2 can go into 5.0 no more than twice. So it does 5 - 2.2(2) which is .6

Comment: @user3117347 for `x % y` it finds that `y` fully divides `x` `a` times then gives you the remainder. Meaning `y * (a + 1)` would be greater than `x` and `y * a` is less than `x`. It gives you difference between `x` and `y *a` or `x - (y * a)`