# modulo function

Tags: c#, floating-point, precision, floating-accuracy

Newbie in C#, trying to work out a simple calculation.

```
float old x=300   
float Distance=300   
float pitch=0.8
int sign=1
```

`new x= old x - (sign * (Distance % pitch) * 0.5 f)`

The value generated by program for new x is `299.6` (which I don't understand).

The value for  `(Distance % pitch)` is `0.7999955`. If you calculate manually `300 modulo 0.8` is `0`. I am guessing modulo function behaves differently for float values but i don't know how. Or it is calculated as 300 percentage of 0.8?

Explanation on this will be much appreciated.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20671518

Comment: This is a typical problem with floating point numbers...

Answer (score 1):

Never expect binary floating-point calculations (using `float` or `double`) on decimal floating point values (e.g. `0.8`) to give exact results.

The problem is that most of decimal numbers cannot be represented exactly in a binary floating-point format. You can think of it as trying to represent `1/3` in a decimal notation. It's not possible.

In your case, `0.8f` is not really `0.8`. If you cast the value to `double` to get some extra precision, you will see it's closer to `0.800000011920929`

```
float pitch = 0.8f;
Console.WriteLine((double)pitch);  // prints 0.800000011920929
```