# in c# how to check if number is whole or exact half

Tags: c#

In c# how to check if number is whole or exact half ?

for example 18, 20.5, and 21 are all valid inputs; 19.75 is not.

Answer (score 11):

`(myNum * 2) % 1 == 0`
would handle both scenarios

Answer (score 1):

```
if ((num % 1 == 0) || 
    ((num + 0.5) % 1 == 0))
    // it is whole or exact half
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static bool modFloat(float number)
    {
        if (number % 0.5 == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

works as well. Modify to double as needed. Note that you can't do this in neither C nor C++. For a more detailed answer on float datatype and modulus, check [How does modulus operation works with float data type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20671518/how-does-modulus-operation-works-with-float-data-type)